Matching the major and minor axis ends of the ellipse in the perspective projection of the circle
I mostly get the circle as an ellipse in perspective projection, but I could not understand exactly which parts of the circle in space correspond to the major and minor axis ends of this ellipse, I am trying to create a structure with geogebra 3d to understand, but I could not figure out what kind of structure I should create, especially working with 3 dimensions is quite challenging.
https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ecbfsyrs
Another point I am curious about in this problem is whether the center of the circle passes through one of the axes of the ellipse, according to my observations, it seems like it always passes through the minor axis, but these observations may not be precise because I cannot create perfect structures.
